# Problem in integrating 'com.google.gms.google-services' plugin with android app

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, google-play-services

When I'm trying to put apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the bottom of my build gradle or anywhere else inside my apps build gradle I get the following error:

```
In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[19.0.
2]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label:18.0.3 -> com.google.android.gms:play-servic
es-vision-common@[19.0.2], but play-services-vision-common version was 19.1.0.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-object-detection-model@{strictly 19.0.5}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@{strictly 19.1.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@{strictly 24.0.3}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-internal-vkp@{strictly 17.0.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-object-detection-model@19.0.5
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@24.0.3
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label@{strictly 18.0.3}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection@16.1.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@{strictly 20.1.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection@{strictly 16.1.0}

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
uild.gradle file.
```

My build.gradle at app level is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mlkitfacedetection"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-object-detection-model:19.0.5'
    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta03"
// CameraX core library using camera2 implementation
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
// CameraX Lifecycle Library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
// CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha10"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am unable to resolve the error. The same code in another app is working absolutely fine.
I am using google-serivices.json file from another app registered on firebase. Isn't it the cause of problem?

Comment: same issue for `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection:16.0.0'` ?

Comment: No, above mentioned implementation is working fine. Only when i am adding this plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services', the code is giving error. I am using google-serivices.json file from another app. Isn't it the cause of problem?

Comment: `Only when i am adding this plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services', the code is giving error. I am using google-serivices.json file from another app. Isn't it the cause of problem? ` yes

Answer (score 2):

I tested this workaround and this seems to work. Add the following in your `dependencies` block:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label:18.0.4'
```

Comment: Yes, but why? I dont want to add a random depedency to the project no idea whats it doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.1'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.2"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label:18.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0'
```

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:20.0.2'
```

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:22.0.4'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.0.0'
```

Follow this link for more detail-
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1904

Answer (score 0):

You may just have to update your dependencies: **File-->Project Structures-->Dependencies** Then in the lower part you will see any dependencies that need updating...Worked for me