# Firebase ML-vision and admob plugins in same Flutter project problem - play services version conflict

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-play-services

Getting really frustrated with this - so I have a project in Flutter with these dependecies among others:

```
firebase_admob: ^0.10.2
firebase_ml_vision: ^0.9.9
```

While I had only `firebase_ml_vision` everything compile smoothly, but adding admob changed that and now the error I'm getting is this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[19.0.
  2]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

  Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-co
  mmon@[19.0.2], but play-services-vision-common version was 19.1.0.

  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@{strictly 24.1.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_ml_vision' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@20.0.
  0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@{strictly 19.1.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label@{strictly 18.0.4}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@{strictly 20.0.0}

  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
  endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
  github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }" to your bu
  ild.gradle file.
```

So far I tried everything I could think of, including juggling versions and so on.

Is there any way to fix this?

*UPDATE*

After some more experiments, I added `googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true` to my build.gradle, so apparently, apart from many deprecation warnings (hello Firebase), this is the real problem:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zze found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzf found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzg found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzh found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzi found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzv found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzw found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

Still no solution though.

*UPDATE 2*

While looking for way to fix this, I found this set of tips to fix the "known issue": https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#mlkit-self-serve-fixes

Authors of the Flutter plugin could, I don't know, try implement them too?!

So I tried to implement it, obvious place was the build.gradle file of the firebase_ml_vision library (I didn't want to make a fork on github, so just for testing purposes edited the file on my drive), I changed one line and added two more from the "solution" linked above:

```
        api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.1'
```

Original line had the `firebase-ml-vision:20.0.0`

Compilation failed again, BUT, I didn't give up and went one step further to just try make this work and for whatever reason decided to try comment out the line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in my project's `android/app/build.gradle` file.
With this change the project finally compiled, but of course, having it disabled caused other problems, like application not initializing the Firebase plugin, so in the end it's still a failure. The search continues...

*UPDATE 3*

Third time's the charm - I decided to fiddle with it a bit more and again added `googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true` to my gradle file. It worked. Project compiles, Firebase init goes okay and even the admob banner shows, although spewing errors on every refresh. Sigh. This is barely a solution, whoever makes decisions on when to push such libraries (with "self-serve" fixes like this mess) into production should be very ashamed.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue with Firebase libraries, you should be able to put `any` next to the version of the library like so:

```yaml
firebase_admob: any
firebase_ml_vision: any
```

Then run `flutter pub get`

Then check you `pubspec.lock` file and check the versions for the libraries then fill them in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Your conflicts should be gone then.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question or you need further explaining!

Comment: I did as you say, but the libraries in pubspec.lock always get same (latest) version numbers, so it didn't change anything.. (was running `flutter clean` before pub get to be sure - didn't help)

Comment: Intresting, I saw you wrote an answer on Github, please check this post out if you haven't already and please let me know if you have already! https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1904

Comment: As well as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056088/problem-in-integrating-com-google-gms-google-services-plugin-with-android-app

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, still can't find any way to solve it.. pls check my updated question. If I was doing all this in pure Java, I'm sure I'd be able to solve it, but this is Flutter and each plugin has it's own set of dependencies and.. duh. Reminds me of DLL-hell days.